# Why is الْمُتْعَةِ translated as "Hajj-at-Tamatu"?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, arabic-translation, nikah-al-mutah

[**The following Hadith**](http://sunnah.com/urn/178460) has been narrated in the Book Sahih Al-Bukhari:

> **حَدَّثَنَا مُسَدَّدٌ، حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى، عَنْ عِمْرَانَ أَبِي بَكْرٍ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو رَجَاءٍ، عَنْ عِمْرَانَ بْنِ حُصَيْنٍ ـ رضى
>   الله عنهما ـ قَالَ أُنْزِلَتْ آيَةُ الْمُتْعَةِ فِي كِتَابِ اللَّهِ
>   فَفَعَلْنَاهَا مَعَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم، وَلَمْ
>   يُنْزَلْ قُرْآنٌ يُحَرِّمُهُ، وَلَمْ يَنْهَ عَنْهَا حَتَّى مَاتَ قَالَ
>   رَجُلٌ بِرَأْيِهِ مَا شَاءَ‏.‏**

And Here is the translation of the Hadith:

> **The Verse of Hajj-at-Tamatu was revealed in Allah's Book, so we performed it with Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), and nothing was revealed in
>   Qur'an to make it illegal, nor did the Prophet (ﷺ) prohibit it till he
>   died. But the man (who regarded it illegal) just expressed what his
>   own mind suggested.**

My question is: why has the word " **الْمُتْعَةِ** " been translated to "Hajj-at-Tamatu", rather than the more literal translation of this word which is "temporary marriage"?

Comment: Should ask the translators

Answer (score 2):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

So, here is the answer [in arabic](http://alfajrsite.net/forum/showthread.php?t=14153)...

I will be translating some of the parts of this answer here.

> ففي صحيح البخاري عن عمران بن حصين رضي الله عنهما قال : أُنْزِلت آية
>   المتعة في كتاب الله ففعلناها مع رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ، ولم
>   يَنْزِل قرآن يحرمه ، ولم يَـنْه عنها حتى مات . قال رجل برأيه ما شاء .
>   
>  وفي رواية لمسلم : قَالَ عِمْرَانُ بْنُ حُصَيْنٍ : **نَزَلَتْ آيَةُ
>   الْمُتْعَةِ فِي كِتَابِ اللَّهِ - يَعْنِي مُتْعَةَ الْحَجِّ**  وَأَمَرَنَا بِهَا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ 
>   ثُمَّ لَمْ تَنْزِلْ آيَةٌ تَنْسَخُ آيَةَ مُتْعَةِ الْحَجِّ ـ وَلَمْ
>   يَنْهَ عَنْهَا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ
>   حَتَّى مَاتَ . قَالَ رَجُلٌ بِرَأْيِهِ بَعْدُ مَا شَاءَ .

Tranlsation

> So **in sahih al-bukhari**... The Verse of Hajj-at-Tamatu was revealed in
>   Allah's Book, so we performed it with Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), and
>   nothing was revealed in Qur'an to make it illegal, nor did the Prophet
>   (ﷺ) prohibit it till he died. But the man (who regarded it illegal)
>   just expressed what his own mind suggested.
>  And **in the narration
>   of Sahi Al-Muslim**... 'There was revealed the **verse of المتعة meaning
>   Tamattu' in Hajj** in the Book of Allah and the Messenger of Allah (may
>   peace be upon him) commanded us to perform it. and then no verse was
>   revealed abrogating the Tamattu' (form of Hajj), and the Messenger of
>   Allah (may peace be upon him) did not forbid to do it till he died. So
>   whatever a person said was his personal opinion. A hadith like this is
>   transmitted on the authority of Imran b. Husain, but with this
>   variation that he ('Imran) said: We did that (Tamattu') in the company
>   of Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) and he did not say
>   anything but he (the Holy Prophet) commanded us to do it.  Sahih
>   Muslim, Book 007, Number 2831 - The Book of Pilgrimage - (English
>   version)

So, **by the hadith of Al-Muslim there are words of sahabi specifying the meaning of this word here.(i have bold those words in arabic and translation)** You may know that one word has many meaning in different contexts. And here the meaning in translations is not assumed, it is by this hadith in sahi muslim.

In the link above you will also find answer to other ahadith having words like this which rafadhi/shia sometimes use to show people that mutta is halal by sunni narrations too. And answer is mentioned for all of them.

### Allah Knows best